# C++ Qt - удаление экземпляра класса

Tags: c++, qt

Знаю, вопрос нубский, но все-же. С Qt я не работал.

Производятся некие операции с участием `QTextStream`.

Затем я пробую его удалить через `delete` и компилятор выдает ошибку.
Я смотрю методы и не обнаруживаю ничего похожего на методы `close`, `Dispose`(это уже из C#).

Так как удалять экземпляры подобных объектов? Утечку памяти словить не хочется.

Текст ошибки:

> ошибка: C2440: delete: невозможно преобразовать "QTextStream" в "void*"
>   Для выполнения данного преобразования нет доступного оператора преобразования, определенного пользователем, или вызов оператора невозможен

```
QTextStream qtin(stdin);
QString input = qtin.readLine();
delete qtin;
```

Comment: Текст ошибки мы всем стеком будем угадывать?

Comment: Не обязательно быть такой язвой, я полагал, это довольно распространенная проблема новичков в Qt. В любом случае, текст ошибки добавлен

Comment: а теперь показывайте код, который вы написали. К третьей пятилетке мы с вами такими темпами сформулируем вопрос, на который можно будет ответить без шаманских приемов.

Comment: на ваш вопрос ответить очень сложно, потому как вы делаете что-то очень странное - пытаетесь экземпляр, созданный на стеке (что следует из текста ошибки) превратить в указатель, а затем, удалить.

Comment: Никакого стека нет, приложил код

Comment: Ну может не на стеке, может в сегменте данных, из фрагмента кода точных выводов сделать нельзя. Но факт в том, что вы этот экземпляр объекта не создавали с помощью `new`, стало быть и удалять с помощью `delete` его нельзя.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Экземпляр `QString` создается на стеке и является локальным. Он будет удален автоматически, когда пропадет из области видимости.

Напоминаю, что областью видимости переменной является блок `{}` в котором она объявлена. Исключение - глобальные переменные, то есть переменные, объявленные вне текста функций. Однако, качественный дизайн приложения **прямо запрещает** любые глобальные переменные.

Ваша третья строчка `delete qtin;` просто не нужна.

О вашем утверждении "никакого стека нет". Стек есть. Под стеком здесь понимается область памяти приложения, куда попадают все локальные переменные. Она организована как стек, причем с аппаратной поддержкой, на уровне инструкций процессора.

Comment: **> Исключение - глобальные переменные**

И статические поля классов и статические переменные внутри функций)